# How to click random pop up during a loop?

Tags: python, selenium

in my scraping script in python I'm in a situation where, while collapsing multiple buttons on a page, randomically a couple of pop up appear in the page and automatically the script fails.

These two pop ups are already managed and the beginning of the script but the website in a non systematic way dedices to show these two.

This is the part of the script interested where the script sleeps for 3 secs between one click to the other:

```
collapes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.suf-CompetitionMarketGroup suf-CompetitionMarketGroup-collapsed ')
for collapes in collapes:
    collapes.click()
    sleep(3)
```

These are the two lines of the scipt where I click on the pop ups at the beginning

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div').click()
```

DO you think there's a way to continue running the process being ready to click on these two without going on error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to close the popups every time your code in for loop fails:

```
def try_closing_popups():
    try:
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[3]/div').click()
    except:
        pass

collapes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.suf-CompetitionMarketGroup suf-CompetitionMarketGroup-collapsed ')
for collapes in collapes:
    try:
        collapes.click()
    except:
        try_closing_popups()
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: In this case it performs the click button for both click on the same times or it works when one of the two appears?.

Comment: In this case it tries to click both but fails to click the second one if the first doesn't exist. Divide the popup clicks to separate try-except blocks to handle all cases